# React nodemailer net.isIP is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-api, nodemailer

I am trying to make a contact page with react and I'm struggling with sending the e-mail part.

I'm trying to use `nodemailer`, and my code for that is:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var xoauth2=require('xoauth2');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    xoauth2:xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
      user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        clientId: '',
        clientSecret: '',
        refreshToken:''
    })
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'Name <mymail@gmail.com>',
  to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email to test Node.js nodemailer',
  text: 'That was easy to test!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent');
  }
});
```

I have put the `clientId`, `clientSecret` and `refreshToken` from google API and oauth2 playground and enabled the non secure apps thing. But when I'm trying to send the e-mail I get
**TypeError: net.isIP is not a function**

EDIT: I have tried adding after `service: 'gmail'`

> type: 'SMTP',
>         host: 'smtp.gmail.com',

Still not working

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue when trying to implement the nodemailer code client side. The reason was because nodemailer doesn't seem to work in the browser (only in node). Moving it serverside (into an express app) solved the issue.

This post regarding the same error (but affecting a different library) also suggests that running the files in the browser is the problem: http://www.ganzhoupress.com/github_/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1981

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

with this:

```
var nodemailer = window.require('nodemailer');
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: This answer seems more like a guess than an actual answer. `nodemailer` requires node.js, and will not work in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nextjs,

Shift the function which calls `nodemailer.sendMail` function to a seperate directory and start as

`"use server"`,

so it knows that it needs to run in the server.