# Can't send email from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a script which is comparing data from client and API and if data on API is > than on client = call Email script.

I'm trying to use [SmtpJS Library](https://www.smtpjs.com/).

Here is part of the code which is suppose to call email script when API data is > than on client.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      getApiData();
    }, 1000 * 60);
    if (dataApi.length > 0) {
      const clientQueriesNames = queries.map(rec => rec.symbol);
      const newFilteredArray = dataApi.filter(apiQuery => {
        if (clientQueriesNames.includes(apiQuery.Symbol)) {
          return apiQuery.Open >
            queries.find(rec => rec.symbol === apiQuery.Symbol).price
            ? apiQuery
            : false;
        }
      });
      const newQueries = queries.filter(rec => {
        return typeof newFilteredArray.find(
          query => query.Symbol === rec.symbol
        ) === "undefined"
          ? rec
          : false;
      });
      setFiltered(newFilteredArray);
      setQueries(newQueries);
      localStorage.setItem("queries", JSON.stringify(newQueries));
      newFilteredArray.forEach(symbol => { Email.send({
        Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        Username: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USER,
        Password: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASS,
        To: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_RECEIVER,
        From: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USER,
        Subject: `${symbol} is up`,
        Body: ""
      }).then(message => alert(message))
      })
      console.log(newFilteredArray);
    }
  }, [dataApi]);
```

I receive an error in console that - `'Email' is not defined  no-undef` at this line of code

```
      newFilteredArray.forEach(symbol => { Email.send({
```

My goal is to send email from React. I was trying to use NodeMailer but I stuck with the same problem and as I understand NodeMailer doesn't work from React - [React nodemailer net.isIP is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163689/react-nodemailer-net-isip-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Did you import your `Email` class in the file you are implementing the above code? Chances are your .js file does not get loaded

Comment: @Constantin I did accordingly to smtpjs documentation and insert smtpjs CDN in index.html but I didn't import Email class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `Email.send` and you're in **React webpack scope**.

Use:

`window.Email.send()`

As a side-note, always make sure `smtpjs.js` loads first and is *not* loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes it's worked for me and error disappears. I triggered email and receive an alert that it's sended, but I didn't receive it on my email, any ideas why it's happens?