# Sending email via app written in Electron/React/TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-api, gmail

I'm trying to implement email/gmail sending mechanism in my application. This is a desktop application with the hosted content written with the help of React and Electron. I've been trying to implement it in a various ways described on the web, using various modules, *googleapi* etc but always ended up with some weird error and even more enigmatic issue description - the code was usually based on the "Node.js" section of the article. I don't know if I fully understand the architecture side of this problem and if it is even possible to trigger the sending mechanism or is it something that has to be implemented in form of a server-side service. If anyone could shed some light on the issue I would greatly appreciate it as I've already spent **too** many hours on the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should choice some method like https://nodemailer.com/about/ or any... there is many. and then if you stuck show us minimal repreduction of your error then we can help. now you only describe that you have some error with some solutions so ... now i can say "I'm sorry for that" :(

Comment: I suspect that you have problem with SMTP. First step in nodemailer : "Create a Nodemailer transporter using either SMTP or some other transport mechanism"

Comment: Hey Robert, yes I've tried to use nodemailer as described in https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799, but ended up with an exception "Uncaught TypeError: net.isIP is not a function" described in more here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16579

Comment: maybe just do the same, move sending mails to small node api (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163689/react-nodemailer-net-isip-is-not-a-function)

Comment: you need some client side library like https://smtpjs.com/.But this is not well secured. Because you have some credential in your code on in react app so not production solution i think. but guys from smtpjs claim that is save.....

Comment: advantage of build your mail api is that when you change some config of mailbox, address, password ... you don't have to force user to download new working version of your app.

Comment: I just had an epiphany, I will get back in a second...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out (finally!). I'm writing it down here in hope it will help someone in future.

The main reason why all tries and methods failed on me was that I was implementing them on the rendering/browser process rather then main electron/node process (from Electron's [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process)). When I moved implementation described in details in [this](https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799) article (approach utilising *nodemailer*) to the main process, which in my case was pretty much comprised just of *electron.js*, and triggered it via *ipc* (Inter-process communication) from the rendering process it miraculously started to work!

Thanks Robert for pointing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163689/react-nodemailer-net-isip-is-not-a-function) issue out, as the following statement put me on the right path.

> I was facing the same issue when trying to implement the nodemailer code client side. The reason was because nodemailer doesn't seem to work in the browser (only in node). Moving it serverside (into an express app) solved the issue.

```
// electron.js
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

function SendIt() {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "your_email@gmail.com",
      pass: "your_password",
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "your_email@gmail.com", 
    to: "recepient@gmail.com",
    subject: "Subject of your email",
    html: "<p>Your html here</p>",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(info);
  });
}

electron.ipcMain.on("SendIt", (event, args) => {
  console.log("ipcMain: Executing SendIt");
  SendIt();
});
```

Comment: Be weary that doing this in an electron application will expose the credentials of your SMTP account to anyone that has access to it. If you need to do this for a production application (and not for something like an email client), I strongly suggest using a backend service that contains your credentials and have the client interface with that directly..

Comment: I understand it exposes user's email account name as well as the password associated with as in the end those string values are compiled into final executable? Or is there another case where those values are exposed to unwanted eye (possibly some network communication?). Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Electron apps can be easily decompiled to its source JS. Of course network communication is less likely with TLS, but trusted self-signed CAs can break that as well.

Comment: @Eric Please if you can share the angular code as well where you "triggered it via ipc from the rendering process"

Comment: @Eric thanks for this post. I am trying to figure out how to send mail via my Quasar/Electron app.  In your code above, I don't quite understand... Do you put the "var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");" in the electron-preload.js file, and then the rest of the code goes into an individual page?  Or does it all have to go into the electron-*.js file? Electron now has electron-preload.js and electron-main.js. Thanks!

Comment: My preload.js only consist of one line `window.ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;` and the use of nodemailer instance is within a normal js file

Comment: @Eric gotcha!  When I put the nodemailer code into my Quasar/Electron electron-proload.js, it works! Then whenever I start the electron app, the email is fired off.  Now I have to figure out how to reference that preloaded stuff in my main Quasar/Electron page.  Hm...

Comment: Late to the discussion, but is loading credentials from `.env` safe if done on the main process?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is using Quasar/Electron and wants to use nodemailer. This works for me.  I'm replying to this post because it's relevant to electron.  As stated by the original author, nodemailer must be run as a node process and can't be run on the renderer process.

I put the nodemailer code inside the electron-preload.js file (under the src-electron directory).

Electron uses Context Isolation.  Therefore, the nodemailer code needs to be put into the electron-preload.js file. Just putting it in any old .vue file will cause an error.  The error I was getting was: nodemailer.createTransport is not a function

In order to overcome the Context Isolation, I had to use the Context Bridge as explained in this electron documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation

For testing purposes, I'm using ethereal.email as suggested in the nodemailer docs.

electron-preload.js:

```
import { contextBridge } from 'electron'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
    doAThing: (emailFrom, emailTo, emailSubject, emailHTML) => {
         var nodemailer = require("nodemailer")

 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
     auth: {
          user: 'user@ethereal.email',
          pass: 'password'
      },
  })
  
    const mailOptions = {
      from: emailFrom, 
      to: emailTo,
      subject: emailSubject,
      html: emailHTML,
    }
  
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(info);
    })
      console.log("in the PreLoad Script")
    }
 }) // end contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld
```

Then, in my .vue file (I'm calling mine personDetails.vue), I have a button, and when clicks it fires off this method:

```
 async sendEmailMethodSMTP() {
      myAPI.doAThing(this.emailFrom, this.emailTo, this.emailSubject, this.emailHTML )
    }, // end sendEmailMethodSMTP
```

I'm collecting the variable information in the information I'm passing from the .vue file (this.emailFrom, this.emailTo, this.emailSubject, this.emailHTML), to the doAThing method in the electron-proload.js file.

When the button is pressed, the information is passed to the preloader, nodemailer is fired off, and the email is sent.

I have not compiled my Quasar/Electron app to make sure this works in a live environment, but running quasar in dev mode this is working great.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thank you!
A little addition: In order to get it working, you have to add "sandbox: false" to webPreferences in the createWindow() function in electron-main.js. The default comment in electron-preload.js also tells you about that.